# Cómo mover placeholder en CSS y HTML?

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando mover el label hacia arriba, como los formularios de google en css para un formulario, si hace su función de subir, cuando coloco mi cursor y escribo algo, sin embargo al momento de querer llenar otro campo el label se coloca en el mismo sitio que el imput y se sobre ponen, mi duda es como hacer para que se quede arriba...

En mi html si coloco el `required` anexo mis codigos html y css en la demostración

Tambien me gustaria saber si hay alguna opción para poder hacer que el select tambien se se suba el label o el `option` donde dice seleccione su opción, y si me pudieran explicar como hacerlo

Este es mi css:

```
    padding: 10x 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-form {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}

.contact-form form div {
    position: relative;
}

.contact-form form div p label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    color: #999;
    transition: .5s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.contact-form input:focus~label,
.contact-form:valid~label {
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-form input:focus,
.contact-form:valid {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}




.contact-form input {
    padding: 10x 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-form {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}

.contact-form form div {
    position: relative;
}

.contact-form form div p label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    color: #999;
    transition: .5s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.contact-form input:focus~label,
.contact-form:valid~label {
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-form input:focus,
.contact-form:valid {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
<div class="contact-form">
                <h3>CAPTURA DE DATOS</h3>
                <h4>Por favor, llena los campos que a continuación se presentan. Estos datos aparecerán en tu certificado, se cuidadoso.</h4>
                <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="insertarDatos.php" method="POST" class="formulario_usuarios">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="30" required="">
                            <label class="form-label">Nombre(s)</label>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" maxlength="30" required="">
                            <label class="form-label">Apellidos</label>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="curp" name="curp" maxlength="18" required>
                            <label class="form-label">CURP (Solo ciudadanos mexicanos)</label>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50" required>
                            <label class="form-label">Correo electrónico</label>

                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>
                            <select name="curso" id="curso" class="group">
                        <option value="ISO 9001:2015 Sistemas de gestión de la calidad.">ISO 9001:2015 Sistemas de gestión
                            de la calidad.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 14001:2015 Sistemas de gestión ambiental.">ISO 14001:2015 Sistemas de gestión
                            ambiental.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 45001:2018 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad y salud en el trabajo.">ISO
                            45001:2018 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad y salud en el trabajo.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 28000:2007 Sistemas de gestión para la seguridad de la cadena de suministro.">ISO
                            28000:2007 Sistemas de gestión para la seguridad de la cadena de suministro.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 37001:2016 Sistemas de gestión antisoborno.">ISO 37001:2016 Sistemas de gestión
                            antisoborno.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 39001:2012 Sistemas de gestión de la seguridad vial.">ISO 39001:2012 Sistemas de
                            gestión de la seguridad vial.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 31000:2018 Gestión del Riesgo - Directrices.">ISO 31000:2018 Gestión del Riesgo –
                            Directrices.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 21001:2018 Sistemas de gestión para organizaciones educativas.">ISO 21001:2018
                            Sistemas de gestión para organizaciones educativas.</option>
                        <option value="ISO 19011:2018 Directrices para la auditoría de los sistemas de gestión.">ISO
                            19011:2018 Directrices para la auditoría de los sistemas de gestión.</option>
                        <option value="Control Estadístico de Procesos con Minitab 19.">Control Estadístico de Procesos con
                            Minitab 19.</option>
                        <option value="Auditorias Remotas frente al Covid 19.">Auditorias Remotas frente al Covid 19.
                        </option>
                        <option value="Análisis de Ciclo de Vida.">Análisis de Ciclo de Vida.</option>
                    </select>
                            <label class="form-label" for="curso">Seleccionar curso</label>

                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="boton">
                        <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" id="btnSend" name="btnSend">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: Quizas te sirva usar materializecss de google: https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html

Answer (score 0):

Puede que haya mejor forma de hacerlo, pero a mi me funciona asi:

**Cambia esto:**

```
*.contact-form input:focus~label,
.contact-form:valid~label {
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**por:**

```
.focus {
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**carga jquery y agrega al final:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function() {
        $(this).siblings().addClass("focus");
    });
    $("input").focusout(function() {
        if ($(this).val() <= 0) {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("focus");
        }
    });
})
```

No colocaste el reset de tu css, verifica los padding o margin para ubicar los textos.

***Aquí el código completo:***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus(function() {
        $(this).siblings().addClass("focus");
    });
    $("input").focusout(function() {
        if ($(this).val() <= 0) {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("focus");
        }
    });
})
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;}
.contact-form input {
    padding: 10x 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.contact-form {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}

.contact-form form div {
    position: relative;
}

.contact-form form div p label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    color: #999;
    transition: .5s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.focus {
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-form input:focus,
.contact-form:valid {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact-form">
    <h3>CAPTURA DE DATOS</h3>
    <h4>Por favor, llena los campos que a continuación se presentan. Estos datos aparecerán en tu certificado, se cuidadoso.</h4>
    <form id="formulario" name="formulario" action="insertarDatos.php" method="POST" class="formulario_usuarios">

        <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="30" required="">
                <label class="form-label">Nombre(s)</label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" maxlength="30" required="">
                <label class="form-label">Apellidos</label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="curp" name="curp" maxlength="18" required>
                <label class="form-label">CURP (Solo ciudadanos mexicanos)</label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <p>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50" required>
                <label class="form-label">Correo electrónico</label>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```